# Jquery validator - Validate only elements with parents visible

Tags: jquery, validation, parent, hidden

I am using jquery validation for required field vaidation.

```
$("#myform").validate();
```

How ignore from validation the required elements with parents hidden?

Eg.

```
 <div id="general" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" class="required" minlength="4"  name="project_name" id="project_name" tabindex="1" maxlength="255" value="project_name" />
    <input type="text" class="required" minlength="4"  name="project_managers" id="project_managers" tabindex="2" maxlength="255" value="project_managers" />
</div>
<div id="folders">
    <input type="text" class="required" minlength="4"  name="folder_name" id="project_name" tabindex="3" maxlength="255" value="project_name" />
    <input type="text" class="required" minlength="4"  name="folder_managers" id="project_managers" tabindex="4" maxlength="255" value="project_managers" />
</div>
```

In this situation i want to ignore from validation the elements from hidden div - "general" .

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349902/jquery-validator-validating-visible-elements-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: { ... }
});
```

But as of version 1.9.0, that is the default and should not have to be declared.
See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate (select "options" and scroll down to "ignore")

Comment: Thanks, its works. I was used  `$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: { ... }
});`

Comment: The same situation, but the form is splited in accordion and i want to validate all visible elements from all ui-accordion-content . By default, jquery validate ignore the hidden elements but in this case the visible elements from colapsed accordion are ignored.

Comment: You could add a classname, eg. `ignore-validation` to the ones you want to ignore, adding `.addClass("ignore-validation")` when you collapse a `<div>` and `.removeClass("ignore-validation")` when you expand.
Then specify `ignore: ".ignore-validation"` in the call to `validate()` to only validate the expanded `<div>`s

Comment: but i want to validate all visible elements from all collapsed or expanded ui-accordion-content.

Comment: the `<div class="ui-accordion-content ....` also has a `style="display: none; ...` so collapsed means not visible. Therefore you cannot use the default `ignore: ":hidden"` functionality if you want to validate collapsed sections. You can use `ignore: ".ignore"` instead, and set `class="ignore"` manually on the sections you don't want to validate.