# jQuery validate only the elements which are visible?

Tags: jquery

In my html page i have 24 fields which have their `class = "emi"`.

Out of these 24  0 , 6 ,12 ,18 or 24 of them can be visible based on the value of a dropdown on my page.

Now i have to perform validations only on the elements which are visible.

I have used jQuery's `.hide()` and  `.show()` to hide and show these elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
// You will get array of visible controls by this code
var elementsToValidate = $('.emi:visible'); //or $('.emi').filter(':visible');
// perform validation using elementsToValidate
```

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore the hidden elements like this

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  ignore: ":hidden",
   rules: {
    name: "required",
    age: "required",
    height: "required"
    }
 });
```

as in this link
[jquery validator - Validating visible elements only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349902/jquery-validator-validating-visible-elements-only)

Also you can do it like this using the not

```
$("#myForm").validate({ignore:":not(:visible)"});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ignore option and set

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

OR

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

of jQuery validate. You can find it in http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/.

Answer (score 0):

This should be like

```
$("#myForm").validate({ignore:":not(:visible)"});
```

use

```
not(:visible)
```

instead of `":hidden"`